# What will happen to you if you're standing near exploding TNT bomb near 20meter away in Vaccum?

Tags: explosions

What I think here could be ,that we'll feel less powerful shock wave as there is no medium of air through which gases can travel . If their is any other possibilities than please suggest !

Comment: How much TNT and in what kind of casing (if any) ?

Comment: So, if there is no atmosphere to slow down the (hypersonic) gases produced from the explosion, how does that change what you would experience?

Comment: But there is no surrounding in which a shock-wave would form, the pressure of the blast would decrease drastically with distance since the gases would simply expand into empty space. Being hit by a few grams of gas at hypersonic speed will not do much (if there's shrapnel from a casing things are different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to add some numbers to your question if you want someone else to do some calculations.

For a simple answer:

- In a vacuum

  - Sound does not travel so you wouldn't suffer overpressure damage to the same extent, though depending on the size of the explosion it could fill the vacuum and increase the pressure enough to kill or injure you.
  - Any shrapnel will travel faster in a vacuum, doing more damage.
  - " ... Outer [space explosions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-altitude_nuclear_explosion#Differences_from_atmospheric_tests) tend to manifest a spherical 'cloud', reminiscent of other [space-based explosions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova) ...".
- Underwater (opposite situation)

  - Sound travels far, and pressure a short distance, resulting in a [bubble pulse](http://www.iusscaa.org/articles/brucerule/acoustic_bubble_pulse_energy.htm).
  - Shrapnel won't travel very far.
  - Direct contact of an exploding device enhances the explosion because the pressure of the water helps direct the explosion towards the most forgiving direction (you, or a sub).

In your case the combination of air and vacuum is closer to the 'all vacuum' example rather than the opposite 'underwater' example. It depends upon what numbers we are talking about whether 20 meters makes a difference, as does the extent of the vacuum and composition of the container.

A huge explosion will create plenty of vacuum. Small explosions are used to protect against explosions in the [Iron Curtain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Curtain_(countermeasure)) or [explosive reactive armor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_armour#Explosive_reactive_armour) methods of tank protection.